# Node.js promise chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js and am able to run these commands one by one one using promises:

```
let promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
sftp.connect({
    host: host,
    username: user,
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync(pemfile)
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.get(remotePath, fs.createWriteStream(localPath));   //This writes from a remote file to a local file
}).then(() => {
    sftp.end();
    resolve();
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message);
        reject(err);
    });
});

await promise1;

let promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(localPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    });
});

let data  = await promise2;
```

This works but I know this is not the best way to do this. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` can be used directly with methods that return promise like `sftp.connect`, `sftp.get`, `sftp.end` so you can use it directly and the function will wait until the step is completed. Only `fs.readfile` does not return a Promise but we can call `fs.promises.readFile()` that returns promise then we can use `await`.

The code can be simplified:

```
try {

    await sftp.connect({
        host: host,
        username: user,
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync(pemfile)

    }) 

    await sftp.get(remotePath, fs.createWriteStream(localPath));   
    await sftp.end();
    let fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(localPath, 'utf8');
    console.log(fileData);

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}
```

The try-catch block has been added to capture errors from any action.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `fs.promises.readFile()` instead of manually promisifying `fs.readFile()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes we can use another module "fs/promises" that export method readFile(fileName, { signal }) and this method return promise

Comment: You can also use `fs.promises.readFile()` without importing another module.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right i edit the answer it becomes more simple. thank you too much